# срабатывание скрипта в зависимости от размера экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт. Как сделать, чтобы он выполнялся если размер экрана <992px, а если экран >992px - не выполнялся

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
    $('.navbar-collapse a').on('click',function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если один раз, и не надо следить за ресайзом, то можно так:

```
window.innerWidth < 992 && (function ($) {
"use strict";
    $('.navbar-collapse a').on('click',function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
})(jQuery)
```

или так, если вас смущает запись через `&&`

```
if (window.innerWidth < 992) { 
    (function ($) {
        ...
    })(jQuery)
}
```

если же надо следить за изменениями размера, то на этот случай есть событие `onresize` у окна

```
window.onresize = function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Супер, работает! Благодарю!!

Comment: @Чайник всегда пожалуйста